# Regex for failing double dashes in a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a naming convention for tokens (simple strings) which has to be followed. Double dashes are the separator of different parts. For example:

- `ActiveDirectory--User--<LastName>--Password`
- `ActiveDirectory--App--<DisplayName>--Secret`

Now I want to check if a token is following the naming convention.

The naming convention says that the token must only contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or dashes (-). Double dashes are not allowed inside `<CustomName>`.

The regex

`^ActiveDirectory--User--([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)--Password$`

works fine if you have the following token as input

`ActiveDirectory--User--Smith--Password`,

but it doesn't check double dashes like

`ActiveDirectory--User--Sm--ith--Password`.

In that case, the word "Sm--ith" would be a group of my match. The desired state should be, that there is no match.

I already tried to use the negated Look Ahead (negation) in combination with Back-References. But I have to become a regex expert before solving such a complex problem.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `^ActiveDirectory--User--((?:(?!--)[a-zA-Z0-9-])*)--Password$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4ahOF/1). Or, `^ActiveDirectory--User--([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)--Password$` (see [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4ahOF/2)).

Comment: How do you plan on forbidding it w/ regex?  Or do you just want the regex to identify it and you'll throw whatever input exceptions you want with other code

Comment: Is `Password` going to be replaced with the actual password in the full string?  I imagine it would be much harder forbidding certain repeated characters from a password

Comment: @KyleMit: The token will be replaced by the base64 encoded password. But the regex will only be used for identify the token.
Here is the workflow:
1. Token `ActiveDirectory--User--AnyAadUser--UPN` is stored in Source Control
2. A custom build agent task is getting the source code and finding the token.
3. Custom build agent searches in the `Active Directory` for an `Application` with the Name `AnyAadApp`. If it finds it then then the task extract the `UPN` and replaces the Token with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your token can have leading and trailing `-`, you may use

```
^ActiveDirectory--User--((?:(?!--)[a-zA-Z0-9-])*)--Password$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4ahOF/1). Here, `(?:(?!--)[a-zA-Z0-9-])*` matches 0 or more ASCII letters or digits or hyphens, but does not match a char if together with the next char it is equal to `--`.

If your token cannot start/end with a `-`, use

```
^ActiveDirectory--User--([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)--Password$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4ahOF/2). Here, `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` matches 1+ letters/digits and then 0 or more repetitions of `-` and 1+ letters/digits.

Comment: Great! You answered my question to 100%. Thanks for that. The token shouldn't but can start with a hyphen. So, i take you're first suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does it all need to be done in one regex? If so, probably go with Wiktor's solution.
If you are writing code that can use more than one regex, a simple method would be to just throw your "no match" code if this matches:

```
".*--.+--.+--.+--.*"
```

That should match any string with with 4 or more sets of double-dashes, which is your stated error case.
As an aside, if you allow trailing/leading single dashes in adjacent "tokens", you'll have ambiguity in your grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're idea works, but I found the best suitable solution by Wiktor's comment